# Pop up radwindow on second application onclick on first application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, timer, telerik

Basically I have two have applications, using same database. I want to pop up a window(may be radwindow) on second application by clicking the button on first application.

what is the better way. I was thinking to update some value on click on first app, and put the timer on second application which after every time period checks the value, if updated , popup the window.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can save the pointer of the second application in your first application,when clicking the button on your first application,you can check the Visible property of the second application,and change the value of Visible property.Just like:

```
Form secondForm;//create a global var to save the pointer of the second application
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (secondForm == null || secondForm.IsDisposed)
    {
        secondForm = new Form2();
        secondForm.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        secondForm.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment. BUT I am working on asp.net web applications. there are two web apps, using same db. I want to both web apps communicate each other.

Comment: May be you can use thickbox to pop up your second app,more information:[thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)